# Find the inverse and the asymptotic expansion of a logarithmic equation $x(y)=y \ln(y)$

Tags: logarithms, inverse-function

Concerning the logarithmic equation  $x(y)=y\ln(y)$, is there an explicit expression for its inverse function $y=y(x)$? 
 Mathematica returns $y=\frac{x}{\text{ProductLog}[x]}$, which should be wrong since its limit for $x\to 0^-$ is $1$ rather than the correct answer $0^+$. 
I am specifically interested in the behavior $x\to 0^-$ and $y\to 0^+$, and looking for an asymptotic expansion. Implied by iteration, I guess that: 
$y=\frac{x}{\ln(-x)}+o[\frac{x}{\ln^2(-x)}]$ 
Is this true? What exactly are next orders?

#### Edit

One more related question: how do `Mathematica` obtain the form $\frac{x}{\text{ProductLog}[x]}$ (here $\text{ProductLog}$ is Lambert-W function as some answers already pointed out)? 
What I've tried is to use substitution $y=\exp(t)$ and obtained $y=\exp[W(x)]$. These two forms are the same. While I still would like to want to know how.

Answer (score 4):

$y\log{y}$ is not injective on $(0,1)$, so Mathematica is giving you one branch of the inverse, which starts at $x=-1/e$, $y=1/e$ and then increases monotonically through $y=1$ at $x=0$ and so on. You can access the other branch, which starts at the same point and decreases to $x=0$, $y=0$ by replacing `ProductLog[x]` with `ProductLog[-1,x]`.

It's quite difficult to approximate this as $x \uparrow 0$: [the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13#E11) offers
$$Wm(x) = -\log{(-1/x)}-\log{\log{(-1/x)}}-\frac{\log{\log{(-1/x)}}}{\log{(-1/x)}} + \dotsb, $$
where $Wm$ is what Mathematica calls `ProductLog[-1,#]&`. One could then divide $x$ by this and use the Taylor expansion of $1/(1-z)$ to get the next couple of terms in the series you are interested in, but it doesn't seem like a good idea to complicate this expansion further!

Comment: The DLMF file helps a lot! The expansion seems to be possible. But why do you think it is not a good idea to complicate the expansion?

Comment: Primarily because the orders of magnitude of the various terms involved can become quite difficult to compare, so the true order of the error is difficult to determine. I'm sure it can be done with enough elbow-grease, but then the question is if it is worth doing so: is the extra accuracy useful in comparison to the time spent acquiring it?

Answer (score 3):

To understand what's going on, it helps to know a bit about Mathematica's `ProductLog[k,x]` function, known more commonly as the Lambert-W function. It arises from trying to invert the function $x(y)=ye^y$. The tricky thing is that, as a graph quickly shows, this function is not one-to-one for all real $y$, and hence there can be no inverse function valid for all $x$. Instead, one must split the domain as $(-1/e,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1/e)$. The function $x(y)=ye^y$ then has the inverse functions $y=W_0(x)$ and $y=W_{-1}(x)$. If we want to get values of $y\in(-1/e,\infty)$, we use the former; otherwise, we use the latter. These are denoted in Mathematica by `ProductLog[0,x]=ProductLog[x]` and `ProductLog[-1,x]`. (There are in fact an infinity of complex-valued branches, but they aren't relevant here.)

To see the relevance, a quick graph of $x(y)=y\ln y$ shows that there's a similar issue here: the function is only one-to-one for $y>0$. (To connect with your numerical observation, note that the line $x=0$ intersects with the graph of $x(y)=y\ln y$ at both $y=0$ and $y=1$.) As a consequence, there are actually two inverse functions corresponding to the two branches; evidently, you want the other one (i.e. replace `ProductLog[x]` with `ProductLog[-1,x]`). A quick use of Mathematica's `Limit` command confirms that $x/W_{-1}(x)\to 0$ from above as $x\to 0^{-}$.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Just wonder why `Mathematica` gives by default only `ProductLog[0,x]`, anyway. A typo in your answer: If focusing on the branch in my question, it should be $x/W_{-1}(x)\to 0$ rather than $1$ as $x\to 0^{-}$.

Comment: @Mathieu Well, when you have Mathematica solve `x==y Log[y]` for $y$, it returns the following warning (along with the solution `{{y -> x/ProductLog[x]}}`): `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.` So it evidently only obtains the solution corresponding to the principal branch, and expects the user to deduce the others.

Comment: As for the typo: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=y\log(y)\implies y=\frac{x}{W(x)}$$ Since you are looking at $x$ around $0^+$, use the expansion $$W(x)=x-x^2+\frac{3 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and long division will give $$y=\frac{x}{W(x)}=1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ If you want better approximations, consider Padé approximants such as $$\frac{3 x+2}{x+2}$$ $$\frac{101 x^2+174 x+60}{17 x^2+114 x+60}$$ $$\frac{18881 x^3+59724 x^2+48780 x+11400}{1927 x^3+28044 x^2+37380 x+11400}$$

Comment: yes you may be right (I haven't check the details) for $x\to0^+$ as I originally posted; but actually I am interested in some other region ($x\to0^-$ and $y\to0^+$) (other statement implies my interests, so some other answers see my intention). sorry for the ambiguity I've made.